# How do we know that CTFT of the autocorrelation function is the PSD?

Tags: fourier-transform, autocorrelation, power-spectral-density

I know that the Fourier Transform of the autocorrelation function is 
the Power Spectral Density. But how can we arrive at such a result intuitively? 
Is it just a theorem?

Comment: It would help to know what you take as the _definitions_ of the autocorrelation function (ACF) and the _power spectral density (PSD)._  Some people just _define_ the PSD as the Fourier transform of the ACF and so there is nothing to prove; others have two different definitions for these concepts and then prove a theorem saying that $\mathbb F(ACF) = PSD$. But to do this, it helps to know the starting point....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
R_x(\tau) &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)x^*(t-\tau)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)e^{j2\pi ft}\,\mathrm df\right]x^*(t-\tau)\,\mathrm dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f) \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^*(t-\tau) e^{j2\pi ft}\,\mathrm dt\right]\,\mathrm df\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f) \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^*(t-\tau) e^{j2\pi f(t-\tau)}\,\mathrm dt\right]e^{j2\pi f\tau}\,\mathrm df\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f) \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^*(\lambda) e^{j2\pi f\lambda}\,\mathrm d\lambda\right]e^{j2\pi f\tau}\,\mathrm df\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f) \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\lambda) e^{-j2\pi f\lambda}\,\mathrm d\lambda\right]^*e^{j2\pi f\tau}\,\mathrm df\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty X(f)X^*(f) e^{j2\pi f\tau}\,\mathrm df\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |X(f)|^2 e^{j2\pi f\tau}\,\mathrm df
\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get to line 4 from line 3 exactly?

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond I multiplied by $e^{-j2\pi f\tau}$ and also by $e^{j2\pi f\tau}$ for a net multiplication by $1$

Answer (score 3):

Here's the story up to constant factors. Correlation is the same as convolution with a time reversed kernel. Autocorrelation is therefore convolution with the time reversed function itself. Convolution can be represented as a product in frequency domain, time reversal as complex conjugation. That means the autocorrelation function of a signal $s(t)$ can be written as $$ ACF[s(t)] = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{s(t)\}\cdot \mathcal{F}\{s(t)\}^*\}$$

Now power spectral density. It is (roughly) defined as the squared magnitude of the frequeny domain representation of the signal. So $PSD[s(t)]=|\mathcal{F}\{s(t)\}|^2$ which we can write using complex conjugation as in $|z|^2=zz^*$

$$ PSD[s(t)] = \mathcal{F}\{s(t)\}\cdot\mathcal{F}\{s(t)\}^*$$

So you can see that $ACF[s(t)]=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{PSD[s(t)]\}$, or $$\mathcal{F}\{ACF[s(t)]\}=PSD[s(t)] $$ which is what you asked for.